# How to calculate running total per month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a table in PostgreSQL:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| '2020-06-02' | 150 |
| '2020-06-03' | 7891 |
| '2020-07-02' | 392 |
| ... | ... |

I need to get running total of numbers in `value` column for each date in table. The sum of `value` in running total has to be calculated over the date range between the first date of month of the date in row and date in the row.

Examples:

- For date `'2020-06-02'` in the first row the sum of `value` column has to be calculated over the range between `'2020-06-01'` and current date (`'2020-06-02'`), including number for current date.
- For the date in the second row the sum of numbers in `value` column has to be calculated over the date range between `'2020-06-01'` and current date (`'2020-06-03'`), including number for `'2020-06-03'`.
- For the third row the sum of numbers in `value` column has to be calculated over the date range between `'2020-07-01'` and `'2020-07-02'`.
- and so on...

How to achieve this? With window functions?

Comment: The result is simply calculated with running total over month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually:

```sql
SELECT date
     , sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', date) ORDER BY date)
FROM   tbl;
```

Note that peer rows (according to your partition and sort order) get the same result. Meaning, duplicate days each get the same running sum including all of their values.